# Trying to push image to DockerHub in containerized Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I'm setting up CI pipeline in Jenkins running in container. I'm using official jenkins/jenkins:latest docker image with no modifications. On Jenkins itself I installed docker plugins and added docker installation in global tool configuration as well as dockerTool in pipeline tools section.

I created container with following command:

```
docker run -d -u root -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

I mounted docker.sock to use part of docker on host machine for building image.
Here is part of Jenkinsfile, that is failing:

```
stage('PUSH') {
        steps {
            script {
                dockerImage = docker.build 'mygithub/spring-petclinic:latest'
                docker.withRegistry( '', 'dockerHubCreds' ) {
                  dockerImage.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The building of image is successful. The build fails only when I'm trying to push image to DockerHub. It says that there is no such file/dir called Docker, but previous step literally printed out docker build command.

I provided logs below.

```
+ docker build -t qeqoos/spring-petclinic:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  63.25MB

Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9
 ---> f7a292bbb70c
Step 2/4 : COPY target/spring-petclinic-2.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/bin/spring-petclinic.jar
 ---> ced11038c9dd
Step 3/4 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in f222a20aad19
Removing intermediate container f222a20aad19
 ---> 3cd6a16e7890
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/usr/bin/spring-petclinic.jar", "--server.port=80"]
 ---> Running in 0a392d01e56b
Removing intermediate container 0a392d01e56b
 ---> 9afe8b544a7b
Successfully built 9afe8b544a7b
Successfully tagged qeqoos/spring-petclinic:latest
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
$ docker login -u qeqoos -p ******** https://index.docker.io/v1/
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:995)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:507)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:518)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.impl.RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.materialize(RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.AbstractEndpointStepExecution2.doStart(AbstractEndpointStepExecution2.java:53)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$run$0(GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.java:77)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there any better approach as for Jenkins in container, or any advice how to make Jenkins push image? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jenkins/jenkins:latest` default won't have `docker client` binary, you just mount `unix socket` to container, it's defintely not enough.

The `command` in output I think just print out: what the docker command it plan to use, not means it already run it.

So, for you, you need to install docker client in `jenkins` container:

- Either use bind mount:

```
docker run -v `which docker`:/usr/bin/docker ......
```

- Or, if the host's docker client not sutiable for container environment, directly download prebuilt `docker client` from [here](https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/), copy the `docker` binary to container.

Comment: nice, I tried out first advice, it worked. I also tried to create image with jenkins and docker, that worked out as well, but the image went from 460MB to 1GB (yikes).
Just wondering, is that a good practice to bind client and bind sockets from host machine onto docker container?

Comment: If you use prebuilt binary(second solution), what you need is just one file `docker`, it's only 50M. `Bind sockets`, for your scenario, it's common way. `Bind docker executable on host to container`: depends on your scenaio, it may break if you change the base image of container, like change container to `alpine` based, but if it's ok on your situation, then that's ok.